# Installing JabRef 5 in ElementaryOS

Tags: thirdpartyapps

I am trying to install version 5.1 of JabRef (ElementaryOS brings 3.8.2) in my system. Up to now I have tried two methods:

1. Install the deb from jabref webpage. In this case, I can open jabref but it is unresponsive (menu options do not work).
2. `snap install jabref`. In this case I get an exception an the program closes when I click in a menu.

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: There is a 3rd option... Installing it from flathub may work: https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.jabref.jabref

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know bout flathub. Unfortunately, I have tried this option but I get same results than using option 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working. In my case the solution was forcing JabRef to use GTK2 instead of GTK3. Here are the steps:

1. Download and install the .deb with `sudo dpkg -i jabref_5.1-1_amd64.deb`
2. Fix dependencies if neccesary `sudo apt-get install -f`
3. Locate the file `JabRef.cfg`. In my case it was in `/opt/jabref/lib/app`.
4. Modify this file and add in the [Java Options] section `-Djdk.gtk.version=2`.

After that JabRef started working flawlessly.

Update:

After I updated to JabRef 5.2, the problem came back. After consulting with JabRef developers in  [github](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/7394#issuecomment-770053469), I had to use this other workaround:

1. Modify the file `/opt/jabref/lib/runtime/bin/JabRef` and add the `-Djdk.gtk.version=2` modifier. Something like this: `"$DIR/java"  -p "$DIR/../app" -Djdk.gtk.version=2  -m org.jabref/org.jabref.gui.JabRefLauncher  "$@"`
2. Modify the launcher so it points to this file. For that I installed `menulibre` (`sudo apt-get install menulibre`) and I modified JabRef entry to point to `/opt/jabref/lib/runtime/bin/JabRef`.

Comment: Nice! You can accept your own answer, sot that other can sfind this solution easier.

Comment: seems I have to wait for two days for doing that. I will do it then! thx.

Answer (score 0):

The best/easy way to install deb files is to use the Eddy app from the AppCenter https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.eddy/

You can also use the Terminal:

`sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb`

Comment: Yes, I installed the deb using dpkg and jabref installs but when I open it, it is unresponsive. Anyone has this app installed in ElementaryOS?